# Why 401 errors is not getting caught with the fetch function in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am using redux approach in react js.I am calling **getRolesPagination()** 
with service **getRolesPagination()** and pass **handleResponse()** in service to catch response/error.
It is working fine but when the server respond with **401** status error it doesn't catch the error.
I have to catch it to log out user because if user token get invalidate then the server responds with 401 status and

> "{error :Unauthorized}"

```
function getRolesPagination(page, filter, sort, pageSize){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request())
        roleService.getRolesPagination(page, filter, sort, pageSize)
        .then(
            response => {
                dispatch(success(response));
            },
            error => {
                dispatch(failure(error));
                dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
            }
        );
    };



function request() { return { type: adminConstants.PAGINATION_ROLES_REQUEST } }
    function success(response)   { return { type: adminConstants.PAGINATION_ROLES_SUCCESS, payload:response } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: adminConstants.PAGINATION_ROLES_FAILURE, payload:error } }
}
```

roleService.getRolesPagination function:

```
function getRolesPagination(page, filter, sort, pageSize){
    const requestOptions = {
        method  : 'GET',
        headers : authHeader()
    };Why 401 errors is not getting caught with the fetch function in reactJS?
    return fetch(baseUrl+'roles?page='+page+'&filter='+filter+'&sort='+sort+'&pageSize='+pageSize, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}
```

handleResponse function:

```
 export function handleResponse(response) {
        return response.json().then(data => {

            if (!response.ok) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    localStorage.removeItem('user');
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
                const error = (data && data.error) || response.statusText;
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
            return data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: 401 is a valid response from the server, you need to check the status of your response if u have to implement authorization

Answer (score 0):

please check the status of the response, 401 is a valid server response it won't go to catch block

```
fetch(request)
.then(function(response) {
 if (response.status !== 200) {
  /*your code */
 }else{
   throw new Error(response.status) 
}
})
.catch(function(error) {
    /*logout logic*/
});
```

Comment: no its not working, my client side and server side are different url's